# Install OpenERP as a four-tiers architecture

Tags: odoo

Instead of 3-tier architecture as described in OpenERP documentation (Database server - OpenERP server - Web client), I would like to make it n-tier (n>3) like this: Database server - OpenERP application server - OpenERP web server - web client. (It means 2 layers of OpenERP tier are separated).

Is it possible and do you know how?
Thank you.

Comment: The [architecture page](https://doc.odoo.com/book/1/1_1_Inst_Config/1_1_Inst_Config_architecture/) clearly explains that the web client (client-web) _is_ the web server.  You can't separate them because they're the exact same thing.  `The client-web component can be thought of as a server or a client depending on your viewpoint.  It acts as a web server to an end user connecting from a web browser, but it also acts as a client to the OpenERP application server.`

Comment: Thank you @yoonix very much for pointing that out, you are right. I didn't explain my question correctly. I made the question again [HERE](http://serverfault.com/questions/692266/install-web-layer-in-openerp-8-as-a-stand-alone-http-server) if you care. I hope you can help