# Install web layer in OpenERP 8 as a stand-alone HTTP server

Tags: http, wsgi, odoo

In Odoo 6.0, when downloading OpenERP, there are openerp web (for web server), and openerp server source code tarball separately. From version 6.1, they made it all-in-one, OpenERP is an HTTP web server, and may also be deployed as an WSGI-compliant application, via Gunicorn, or Apache mod_wsgi (or something else). In OpenERP there are still 2 layers, the OpenERP server and Web layer.

In [OpenERP Servers Developers Documentation for v7.0](https://media.readthedocs.org/pdf/openerp-server/latest/openerp-server.pdf), it's mentioned that Web layer

> It is a WSGI-compliant application. As such, it can be run as a stand-alone HTTP server or embedded inside OpenERP.

Does anyone know possible ways to install those 2 layers as stand-alone, in 2 connected server? I've been searching but I have no clue. Does it mean I have to manually divide the source code, or does it mean I need to install a web server in another machine and config somehow so that it can deploy openerp source code?

Thank you very much.